# Complex _.find() query

Tags: javascript, lodash

Consider this example:

```
var data = { 
  crates:
   { 'crateID':
      { 
        fruit:
         { 'fruitID':
            { 
              attributes:
               { type: 'apple'}
            }
         },
         /*...*/
     }
  },
  /*...*/
}
```

Using `_.find()` (or a set of lodash functions) I wish to return an inner fruit object.

Currently I tried `var fruit = _.find(data.crates, {fruit: {attributes: { type: 'apple'}}});`, however that returns `undefined` presumambly because I've ignored the keys `crateID` and `fruitID`.

I've also tried

```
_.each(data.crates, function (crate) {
     var fruit = _.find(crate.fruit, attributes: { type: 'apple'}}});
});
```

which finds (or not) the fruit for each crate at the time. The problem there is that it feels hacky and also because it's not synchronous, which makes it unsuitable for my needs.

Is there a way to find and return the fruit object using Lodash in a synchronous way (this code is within a function which must return the object)?

Comment: All lodash functions (except the obvious `debounce`,`defer`,`delay`,`throttle`) are synchronous, and `return` the result? Not everything that takes a callback is automatically asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wish to return an inner fruit object.

That means you need to apply `_.find` on a collection of fruits, not on the crates. You could do something like

```
// join fruits from all crates
var fruits = _.merge.apply(_, _.pluck(data.crates, "fruit"));
// or maybe:
var fruits = _.flatten(_.values(_.pluck(data.crates, "fruit")));
var fruit = _.find(fruits, {attributes: { type: 'apple'}})
```

Comment: This works awesomely, thanks! :) I knew some step was needed before I call _.find(), but wasn't sure which one.